# View list of files in ZIP archive on Linux

Tags: linux, zip

How can I view the list of files in a ZIP archive without decompressing it?

Comment: Is it possible to do the same for a regular unix archive? (tar/gzip/bz2/ etc)

Comment: tar tvf.  if .gz, add a z.  For bz2, add j.  Lots more, check the man page.

Answer (score 788, accepted):

The `less` utility is capable of peeking into a `zip` archive.  In fact, if you look at the outputs of `unzip -l zipfile` and `less zipfile`, you will find them to be identical.

Comment: Note, that ```less zipfile``` on MacOS-X displays the binary filecontent, so you see a lot of garbage instead of the content of the zip-file. Then you should opt for the ``ùnzip -l zipfile```

Comment: I get slightly more information from unzip compared to less. Just saying.

Comment: @ayaz In what system does less list zipfiles? I see comments telling that it does not work on MAC, Ubuntu, and here I use Debian. Debian also shows binary garbage.

Comment: In Ubuntu, try ```view [zipfile]```.

Comment: WRONG. unzip -l works well to show the files inside of a zip archive, but less gives out binary content in many cases and that's a mess of course.

Comment: You need the ``lesspipe`` helper installed to enable zip file support for less.  It's standard on many linux systems but not on OSX, but you can install it with brew.

Comment: It's a neat hack to use `less`, but `unzip -l` seems like the canonical answer, esp. given that it's a far more universal answer.

Comment: `zipinfo myFile.zip` produces more info and particularly it lists UNIX file permissions whereas `unzip -l` is less verbose. My comment is based on zipinfo 3.0 and unzip 6.0 dated from April 2009.

Comment: FYI: `.jar` files (java archive) are zip files.

Comment: `view [zipfile]` also works in Debian 10

Comment: view [zipfile] works on macOS

Comment: Less is better where it works, cause you don't need to pipe it to the pager.

Comment: @Samuel Lampa's answer worked well for me.

Answer (score 204):

Try `unzip -l files.zip`
Or  `unzip -l files.zip | less` if there are too many files to be listed in one page.

Also, See `man unzip` for more options

Comment: You can skip the pipe to `less` command. It is great idea in a big collection of files, though.

Comment: You can also add `-v` argument to include verbose details about compression for each file.

Answer (score 134):

To list zip contents:

```
zipinfo -1 myzipfile.zip
```

For detailed output:

```
zipinfo myzipfile.zip
```

Comment: Nice answer, you don't have to parse the output just to get filenames.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a `1` and not an `l`?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen according to `man zipinfo`: `-1 list filenames only, one per line. This option excludes all others; headers, trailers and zipfile comments are never printed. It is intended for use in Unix shell scripts.`

Comment: The `-1` flag matches the `ls` command. `ls -1` prints all files, one line per file.

Answer (score 70):

Please use

```
vim ZIP_FILE_NAME
```

for the same. This is a simple and easy to remember one.

Comment: Nice, this also allows to open individual files in the archive without doing the unzip

Comment: Quite unexpected, and extremely handy! Thanks!

Comment: Actually: this wont work if `unzip` is not installed on the system. Besides that, awesome!

Answer (score 17):

You can make the zip appear as a directory (in which you use `cd`, `ls`, etc.) by mounting it with the [fuse-zip](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) virtual filesystem.

```
mkdir foo.d
fuse-zip foo.zip foo.d
ls foo.d
cat foo.d/README
...
fusermount -u foo.d
rmdir foo.d
```

Another relevant [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem is [AVFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avf/). It creates a view of your entire directory hierarchy where all archives have an associated directory (same name with `#` tacked on at the end) that appears to hold the archive content.

```
mountavfs
ls ~/.avfs/$PWD/foo.zip\#
cat ~/.avfs/$PWD/foo.zip\#/README
...
umountavfs
```

Many modern file managers (e.g. Nautilus, Dolphin) show archive contents transparently.

AVFS is read-only. Fuse-zip is read-write, but beware that changes are only written to the zip file at unmount time, so don't start reading the archive expecting it to be modified until `fusermount -u` returns.

Comment: Nice, Giles. Thanks. Just a quick: can one add files to it by justing "cp"ing to the directory?

Comment: @DrBeco With fuse-zip, yes. With avfs, no.

Answer (score 16):

At least in Ubuntu, the possibly easiest command is:

```
view [zipfile]
```

This will open up the file listing in your standard text editor (nano, vim etc).

Comment: works on macOS too

Answer (score 8):

## A more comprehensive solution: vim || emacs

The previous answer by @kinORnirvana is my favorite **to produce a file** with the content of a zip archive.

```
zipinfo [-1] archive.zip > archive_content.txt
```

However,  I recommend **vim** or **emacs** (not nano) if you need to browse into an archive file or even to view the content of a file contained inside it.

```
vim archive.zip
```

**This approach works with other archive formats too:**

```
vim file.tar
vim file.tar.gz
vim file.tar.bz2
```

With **vim** or **emacs** you can:

- browse the directory structure of the archive file.
- view the content of any file inside the archive file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its actually `unzip -l file.zip | grep "search"` or if you have a lot of files

```
for i in `ls *zip`; do 
  unzip -l $i | grep "search"; 
done
```

Update: Changed from '-p' to '-l' in order to search for files.

Answer (score 2):

If you're more graphically oriented, Midnight Commander can also browse zip files as if they were regular directories.

Answer (score 1):

(yaa) Yet another answer:

Alias this command:

`alias vless='/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh'`

and you can use `vless file.zip` to take advantage of `vi` (or `vim`) less script.

(also good to substitute less, so you can have colors)

Comment: `less -R` *do* support ANSI colors.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to peek inside also with `zmore`,  `zless`, `zcat`, but with `vim` is in a structured way

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
zipdetails yourFileName.zip
```

Comment: Could you possibly include some example outputs? Is zipdetails part of the standard Linux kernel or would the OP need to install this separately?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `zipdetails yourFileName.zip | grep "Filename  "`?

Comment: `Zipdetails displays information about the internal record structure of zip files. It is not concerned with displaying any details of the compressed data stored in the zip file.`
zipinfo seems much more appropriate here

Comment: @zx485 Using Redhat 7, I'm unable to use any commands in other answers, and we're unable to request to install anything on that server. Your solution was useful, thanks!