# Read the contents of a zipped file without extraction just 1 level?

Tags: linux, zip

unzip options -t and -l lists entire zip, even sub directories. Is there an option of unzip to read contents just 1 level ? It should list immediate contents of zip. It should not list *contents of* subdirectories.

I have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/462788/read-the-contents-of-a-zipped-file-without-extraction) and its not a duplicate of it.

Comment: why negative vote ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manpage:

```
[-x xfile(s)]
   An  optional  list of archive members to be excluded from process‐
   ing.  Since wildcard characters  normally  match  (`/')  directory
   separators  (for exceptions see the option -W), this option may be
   used to exclude any files that are in subdirectories.   For  exam‐
   ple,  ``unzip foo *.[ch] -x */*'' would extract all C source files
   in the main directory, but none in  any  subdirectories.   Without
   the  -x  option,  all C source files in all directories within the
   zipfile would be extracted.
```

So the answer is:

```
unzip -l <zipfile> -x '*/*'
```