# get the text inside a zipped text file without extraction

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zip

To get the content of a zipped file, you can do `unzip -p archive.zip file1.txt | less` as said [here](https://superuser.com/questions/462788/read-the-contents-of-a-zipped-file-without-extraction)

However, for that is for the case where you are "positioned" in the path where your .zip is. If you are not (for the case the command being executed in a shell script for example), I guess I would need to pass in the absolute paths for the .zip  and the file, but a `filename not matched:` error is thrown.

For a .zip in the home directory I tried this commands:

`unzip -p ~/archive.zip ~/archive.zip/file1.txt | less`
`unzip -p ~/archive.zip ~/archive/file1.txt | less`

but I get the `filename not matched:` error.

How can I get the content of a txt file, without unzipping using absolute paths? (meaning not having to be in the specific directory of the .zip to run the command or to be able to perform that task form other path or a shell script)

Comment: The second argument referencing file1.txt as if from your home directory (with `~/`) is incorrect.  Try `unzip -l ~/archive.zip` to see the exact path of file1.txt within the zipfile, not in the file system.  I.e., probably just `unzip -p ~/archive.zip file1.txt | less` (though it could be `subdir/file1.txt`)

Answer (score 1):

The -p flag extracts files to pipe insted of unzipping into actual files. You don't need to use any additional path. Use this:

`unzip -p ~/archive.zip file1.txt | less`

I tested it in Centos 8:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do still get the error. I also tried hardcoding the path, changing `~/archive.zip` to `/home/pi/archive.zip`. same result. In case it makes any diffrence this is a raspberrypi OS

Comment: seems that this does the job `unzip -p /home/pi/archive.zip '*/file1.txt'`

Comment: It's weird, maybe some different implementation of the unzip command?